# How can I install the package lifecycle on r studio?

Tags: r, package

I'm trying to install the new version of the package lifecycle, but it didn't work. So i removed it and now it doesn't let me install it. This is the output I get:

```
> install.packages("lifecycle")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/aless/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘cli’, ‘rlang’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
cli        3.2.0  3.6.1              TRUE
rlang      1.0.2  1.1.0              TRUE
lifecycle  1.0.1  1.0.3             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/cli_3.2.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1255499 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/rlang_1.0.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1718546 bytes (1.6 MB)
downloaded 1.6 MB

package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘cli’
Warning in install.packages :
  problem copying C:\Users\aless\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll to C:\Users\aless\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll: Permission denied
Warning in install.packages :
  restored ‘cli’
package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2TQRK3\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘lifecycle’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 106854 bytes (104 KB)
downloaded 104 KB

* installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
* removing 'C:/Users/aless/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/lifecycle'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\aless\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2TQRK3\downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Try starting a new session of R and installing rlang separately.